# TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, user-interface, tkinter

Trying to create a GUI using classes and I keep having problems with this error. I am unsure what it means as I only have one class as far as  I can see, my error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Blaine/Desktop/Computing Project.py", line 5, in <module>
class SneakerSeeker(tk,Frame):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a 
(non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

My code is:

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

class Number1(tk,Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Number1, self).__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.TopTitle = Label("Number1", font = ('Calibri ', 16))
        self.TopTitle.pack()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Number 1")
    app = Number1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to comment you but there are many things to say:

- First of all, get rid of from tkinter import *  and write `import tkinter as tk` instead (as Bryan has written it many times here). Besides this, what the purpose of coding `from tkinter import *`  and `import tkinter as tk` within the same application?  When you do that, all your widget classes must be precedented with `tk` (`tk.Label(...)`, `tk.Frame(...)`...)
- In `class Number1(tk,Frame)` you should write `tk.Frame` (or simply `Frame` if you keep your imports as they are)
- You are using unecessarily `super()` in  `super(Number1, self).__init__()`.  Please read the answer of Bryan here: [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application), and replace that line by this one: `tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)` (for the future, take in consideration [*Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it*](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/))
- Regarding this line: `self.TopTitle = Label("Number1", font = ('Calibri ', 16))`: the first option to pass to `tk.Label()` (and any other widgets you will create) is the parent widget: in your case, `self.master`
- I find the 2 lines  related to `self.TopTitle` useless and I do not understand what you are trying to achieve with them (besides, you should not name that label that way; please respect [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you want to join the Python sect)

Comment: Huh? There's nothing wrong with using `super`. In fact it's better than `tk.Frame.__init__` because you don't have to hard-code the parent class's name.

Comment: Maybe worth saying that the error message is related to second paragraph, a probable typo `tk,Frame` instead of `tk.Frame`